# Vue sorting a frozen list of non-frozen data

Tags: vuejs2

I have a frozen list of non-frozen data, the intent being that the container is not reactive but the elements are, so that an update to one of the N things does not trigger dependency checks against the N things.

I have a computed property that returns a sorted version of this list. But Vue sees the reactive objects contained within the frozen list, and any change to an element results in triggering the sorted computed prop. (The goal is to only trigger it when some data about the sort changes, like direction, or major index, etc.)

The general concept is:

```
{
    template: someTemplate,
    data() {
        return {
            list: Object.freeze([
                Vue.observable(foo),
                Vue.observable(bar),
                Vue.observable(baz),
                Vue.observable(qux)
            ])
        }
    },
    computed: {
        sorted() {
            return [...this.list].sort(someOrdering);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a Vue idiom for this, or something I'm missing?

Comment: Just use `watch` over `someOrdering` instead of computed prop

Comment: a `watch` over the ordering is working well

Answer (score 0):

*...any change to an element results in triggering the sorted computed prop*

I have to disagree with that general statement. Look at the example below. If the list is sorted by `name`, clicking "Change age" does not trigger recompute and vice versa. So recompute is triggered **only if property used during previous sort is changed**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      list: Object.freeze([
        Vue.observable({ name: "Foo", age: 22}),
        Vue.observable({ name: "Bar", age: 26}),
        Vue.observable({ name: "Baz", age: 32}),
        Vue.observable({ name: "Qux", age: 52})
      ]),
      sortBy: 'name',
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sorted() {
      console.log(`Sort executed ${this.counter++} times`)
      return [...this.list].sort((a,b) => {
        return a[this.sortBy] < b[this.sortBy] ? -1 : (a[this.sortBy] > b[this.sortBy] ? 1 : 0)
      });
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Sorted by: {{ sortBy }}</div>
  <hr>
   <button @click="list[0].name += 'o' ">Change name</button>
   <button @click="list[0].age += 1 ">Change age</button>
  <hr>
  <button @click="sortBy = 'name'">Sort by name</button>
   <button @click="sortBy = 'age'">Sort by age</button>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="item in sorted" :key="item.name">{{ item.name }} ({{item.age}})</div>
</div>
```